# Simplifying Boolean Algebra Expression with 3 variables

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can someone help me simplify this in Boolean algebra? It should be one step at a time so I can understand it. The expression is:
$(x+y+z)(x+z)(x'+y+z)$

I tried doing this:  (it's probably wrong, because I think it should simplify to just z?)
$(x+y+z)(x+z)(x'+y+z)$

$(x+y+z)(z+(x+x'+y))$ //distributive property

$z+(x+y+1+y)$ //distributive again

$z+x+y+(x+x')$ //+ identity

$z+x+y+x'$ //+ identity (Edit I know this is wrong, x+x' = 1 not 0, my mistake)

$z+y$ //+ identity

I feel this is wrong, because 'y' and not z wouldn't make the initial expression false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is right:

$(x+y+z)(x+z)(x'+y+z)$

$(y+z+xx')(x+z)$

$(y+z)(x+z)$

$z+yx$

Can someone confirm this please?

Comment: [Avoid asking for clarifications in answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4845/290189) as there is a comment system for that.